# Passing Results from SQL to Google Maps API in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, google-maps, codeigniter

I'm hoping to use Google Maps on my site.

My addresses are stored in a DB. I’m pulling up a page where the information is all dynamic. For example: mysite.com/site/business/5 (where 5 is the id of the business).

Let’s say I do a query like this:

```
function addressForMap($id) {
$this->db->select('b.id, b.busaddress, b.buscity, b.buszip');
$this->db->from('business as b');
$this->db->where('b.id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
```

// add a limit
    $this->db->limit(1);

```
// get the results.. cha-ching
$q = $this->db->get();

// any results?
if($q->num_rows() !== 1)
{
    return FALSE;
}

return $q->row();
```

}

How can I output the info to the Google Maps API correctly so that it displays the map appropriately?

The API interface takes the results like this: `$marker['address'] = 'Crescent Park, Palo Alto';`.

Here's what I have in the controller:

```
$marker = array();
    $address = $this->Business_model->addressForMap($id); //Get result row
    $marker['address'] = $address->busaddress .' '.$address->buscity .', '. $address->buszip;
```

Comment: The problem I'm running into is I get Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$buscity, Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$buszip and Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$busaddress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MODEL

```
function addressForMap($id)
{
    $this->db->select('b.id, b.busaddress, b.buscity, b.buszip');
    $this->db->from('business as b');
    $this->db->where('b.id', $id);

    // add a limit
    $this->db->limit(1);

    // get the results.. cha-ching
    $q = $this->db->get();

    // any results?
    if($q->num_rows() !== 1)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $q->row();
}
```

The CONTROLLER

```
function your_controller_method($id)
{
    $data = $this->Business_model->addressForMap($id);

    // did we get any results?
    if($data === FALSE)
    {
        show_error();
        return;
    }  

    $marker['address'] = $data->busaddress.' '.$data->buscity.', '.$data->buszip;
}
```

Make sure you validate that `$id` is an actual numerical id. It's a good thing to do before actually performing the query.. IMO.

**EDIT #2: See changed code above**

---

**EDIT #1: From your comment and changes**

You've got this:

```
return $this->db->get();
```

when, based on the rest of your code, it should be this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

When you return the query object, the variable `$address` gets assigned the CI result object. so, in your controller, you would actually have to do something like this:

```
$address = $this->Business_model->addressForMap($id);

$row = $address->row();

$marker['address'] = $row->busaddress .' '.$row->buscity .', '. $row->buszip;
```

Still... I would suggest changing `return` to `$query =` and you could keep your controller as it is.

Comment: I updated my post to show what I have for the model and the controller now. The problem I'm running into is I get Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$buscity, Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$buszip and Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$busaddress

Comment: I see where you're problem is and edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: I'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::row() in /home/welcomet/public_html/application/controllers/site.php on line 51 which is: $row = $address->row(); now?

Comment: You need to pick a method... either return the `$q->row()` object and just do `$address->buszip` in your controller, **OR** return the entire query object (`$q`) and do `$row = $address->row()` in your controller. I've edited my answer again to show the model and controller examples.

Comment: i updated the code with the new code. i'm not getting any errors but i'm not getting the map to show the address either. so good and bad.

Comment: If your test site is accessible online, post a link to the page and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I did a print_r of addressForMap($id), it's getting the proper data. it's just not working how i'm placing it into $marker['address'].

Comment: I just wanted to stop by and say thanks again for your help. Your advice really helped me to get a handle on passing the data back and forth between the model and the different functions. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Final correct code:

For the Controller:

```
$address = $this->Business_model->addressForMap($id); //Get result row
        $config['apikey'] = 'google-api-key';
        $config['center_address'] =  $address->busaddress .', '. $address->buscity;
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
        $marker = array();

        // $marker['address'] = $address->busaddress .' '.$address->buscity .', '. $address->buszip;
        $marker['address'] = $address->busaddress .', '. $address->buscity;
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

        $data['address'] = $address->busaddress .', '.$address->buscity;
```

For the Model:

```
function addressForMap($id) {
    $this->db->select('b.id, b.busaddress, b.buscity, b.buszip');
    $this->db->from('business as b');
    $this->db->where('b.id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
// add a limit
    $this->db->limit(1);

    // get the results.. cha-ching
    $q = $this->db->get();

    // any results?
    if($q->num_rows() !== 1)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $q->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using [my library](http://biostall.com/google-maps-api-library-for-codeigniter-framework). It looks I posted the solution on my blog at near enough exactly the same time as you did on here :-P

Glad to hear you got it sorted though!

Comment: Part of what was throwing me, was that I thought the map would center automatically on wherever the marker was placed. I didn't realize that I had to center the map then place the marker. I probably had it working sooner but because no marker was showing on the screen and it stayed showing only Palo Alto, I thought i was still not doing something right.